# mysql if statements how to

Tags: php, mysql, polymorphic-associations

How do i code this in mysql?

if tbl_comments.to is a number then join with tbl_users

if tbl_comments.to is a player key then join with table persons and display names

if tbl_comments.to is a team key then join with table teams and display names

if tbl_comments.to is a league key then join with tbl_sports

Answer (score 2):

The practice of having a column that references one of several possible tables is called *polymorphic associations*.  It's a hack that breaks rules of relational database design.

SQL does not support conditional joins to different tables depending on the value you find in a given row.  All tables must be known at the time the database parses the query.

You could join to *all* those tables with outer joins, because exactly one of those tables should contain a match:

```
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(u.name, p.name, t.name, s.name) AS name
FROM tbl_comments AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_users u ON c.to = u.id AND c.type = 'number'
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_persons p ON c.to = p.id AND c.type = 'player'
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_teams t ON c.to = t.id AND c.type = 'team'
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_sports s ON c.to = s.id AND c.type = 'league';
```

Or you could join to one of those tables but restrict to rows you know match:

```
SELECT c.*, u.name
FROM tbl_comments AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON c.to = u.id 
WHERE c.type = 'number'
  UNION ALL 
SELECT c.*, p.name
FROM tbl_comments AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_persons u ON c.to = p.id 
WHERE c.type = 'player'
  UNION ALL 
SELECT c.*, t.name
FROM tbl_comments AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_teams t ON c.to = t.id 
WHERE c.type = 'team'
  UNION ALL 
SELECT c.*, s.name
FROM tbl_comments AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_sports s ON c.to = s.id 
WHERE c.type = 'league'
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you tell what `tbl_comments.to` is, do you have another column to save the type?

Or you need to join all the tables.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_comments c
LEFT JION ON tbl_users u ON c.to = u.id
LEFT JION ON tbl_persons p ON c.to = p.id
LEFT JION ON tbl_teams t ON c.to = t.id
LEFT JION ON tbl_sports s ON c.to = s.id
```